# How np.argsort works in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following pandas DataFrame named `index`:

```
tz
                       521.0
Africa/Cairo             3.0
Africa/Casablanca        1.0   
Africa/Ceuta             2.0
Africa/Johannesburg      1.0
dtype: float64
```

when I apply `index.argsort()` I get something like this:

```
tz
                       2
Africa/Cairo           4
Africa/Casablanca      3
Africa/Ceuta           1
Africa/Johannesburg    0
dtype: int64
```

Can someone explain to me where the numbers: `2,4,3,1,0` come? I know they're index range from 0 to 4 but I can't find any logic in their order.

Comment: Is there an empty string in the index? and also this looks like a pandas series instead of data frame.

Answer (score 9):

`argsort` returns the index positions of the values being sorted if they were to be sorted.  Keep in mind that this is a numpy function and its assignment to series or dataframe indices is erroneous.

- `2` refers to the item in the `2` position (3rd) was the minimum

  - this was `1.0`
- `4` refers to the item in the `4` position (5th) was next

  - also `1.0`
- `3` (4th position) was a `2.0`
- `1` (2nd position) was a `3.0`
- `0` (1st position) was a `521.0` and the maximum

---

It's more appropriate to assign to an array and use as a slice

```
a = s.values.argsort()
s.iloc[a]

tz
Africa/Casablanca        1.0
Africa/Johannesburg      1.0
Africa/Ceuta             2.0
Africa/Cairo             3.0
                       521.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: actually, it's more appropriate to use `s.sort_values()` , more readable, same effect

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some strange sorting is going on. The example in
[the `argsort` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
x = np.array([3, 1, 2])
np.argsort(x)
```

Gives the sorting order:

```
array([1, 2, 0])
```

One would think the final order is 2,3,1.  But `x[np.argsort(x)]` gives 1,2,3.  Go figure.

Comment: `argsort` returns the indices that sort the array, not the sorted array itself.